# pinch zoom in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, pinchzoom

I am trying to add a pinch gesture zoom in my collection view so what is happening is the zoom is happening each time from the start it is not preserving the previous scale state and the max and min scale limit is also not working
since I am new to to swift I am struggling with this, thanks for the help in advance

here is my collection view controller class

```
import UIKit

class BookViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var seatMapCollection: UICollectionView!

    @IBAction func pinchGesture(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    }

    var dateValue = ["1","2","3","4","10","6","7","8","9","5"]
    var dayValue = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Thu","Thu","Thu","Thu","Thu","Thu"]
    var month = ["jan","feb","mar","apr","Thu","Thu","Thu","Thu","Thu","Thu"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.seatMapCollection.dataSource = self
        self.seatMapCollection.delegate = self
        self.seatMapCollection.maximumZoomScale = 2
        self.seatMapCollection.minimumZoomScale = 0.50
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pinchAction(sender:)))
        seatMapCollection.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: seatMapCollection)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return seatmapCollection.numberOfItems(inSection: 150)
        return 15
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 15
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SeatMapCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SeatMapCollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }

    @objc func pinchAction(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
        var scaleValue: CGFloat!
        if sender.state == .changed || sender.state == .began {
            if scaleValue == nil{
                seatMapCollection.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: sender.scale, y: sender.scale)
                scaleValue = sender.scale
            }else{
                seatMapCollection.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: scaleValue, y: scaleValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my custom collection view layout class

```
import UIKit

class CustomCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    let CELL_HEIGHT = 35.0
    let CELL_WIDTH = 35.0
    let STATUS_BAR = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

    var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    var contentSize = CGSize.zero
    var cellAttrsDictionary = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    var cellPadding = 5.0

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return self.contentSize
    }

    var interItemsSpacing: CGFloat = 8

    // 5
    var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return collectionView!.contentInset
    }

    override func prepare() {

        // Cycle through each section of the data source.
        if collectionView!.numberOfSections > 0 {
            for section in 0...collectionView!.numberOfSections-1 {

                // Cycle through each item in the section.
                if collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: section) > 0 {
                    for item in 0...collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: section)-1 {

                        // Build the UICollectionVieLayoutAttributes for the cell.
                        let cellIndex = NSIndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                        let xPos = Double(item) * CELL_WIDTH
                        let yPos = Double(section) * CELL_HEIGHT
                        let frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: CELL_WIDTH, height: CELL_HEIGHT)
                        let cellFinalAttribute = frame.insetBy(dx:CGFloat(cellPadding) ,dy:CGFloat(cellPadding))
                        let cellAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: cellIndex as IndexPath)
                        cellAttributes.frame = cellFinalAttribute
                        cellAttrsDictionary.append(cellAttributes)

                        // Determine zIndex based on cell type.
                       /* if section == 0 && item == 0 {
                            cellAttributes.zIndex = 4
                        } else if section == 0 {
                            cellAttributes.zIndex = 3
                        } else if item == 0 {
                            cellAttributes.zIndex = 2
                        } else {
                            cellAttributes.zIndex = 1
                        }*/

                        // Save the attributes.
                        //cellAttrsDictionary[cellIndex] = cellAttributes

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Update content size.
        let contentWidth = Double(collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)) * CELL_WIDTH
        let contentHeight = Double(collectionView!.numberOfSections) * CELL_HEIGHT
        self.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        // Create an array to hold all elements found in our current view.
        var attributesInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        // Check each element to see if it should be returned.
        for cellAttributes in cellAttrsDictionary {
            if rect.intersects(cellAttributes.frame) {
                attributesInRect.append(cellAttributes)
            }
        }

        // Return list of elements.
        return attributesInRect
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

here is my custom cell class

```
import UIKit

class SeatMapCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var seatDetail: UILabel!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

    }
}
```

Comment: You can also place a UIScrollView inside collectionview cell, which supports zooming by default.

Comment: i want to zoom the whole collection view will it be possible by adding the scroll view in the cell

Comment: You didn't set CustomCollectionViewLayout as a collection view delegate, did you?